# MyFaces CODI - add to project

Tags: java, maven, jsf-2, myfaces, codi

I'm developing a *maven* JSF web app.
I want to use **@PreDestroy** on some **@ViewScoped** bean, however this is not possible in JSF 2.0 (or not when page is closed or redirected)
I found MyFaces CODI's **@ViewAccessScoped** could be the solution, however I have problems with adding it.
When i try this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.bundles</groupId>
    <artifactId>myfaces-extcdi-bundle-jsf20</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.5</version>
</dependency>
```

it results an error while compiling.

Without the dependency project run well.

I'm enclosing the error log:

```
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Factory 'javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory' was not configured properly.
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.verifyFactoriesExist(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:329)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:235)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:376)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5273)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:895)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:530)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1471)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1436)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:856)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:353)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:581)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.jsf2.impl.listener.request.CodiFacesContextFactory
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getImplGivenPreviousImpl(FactoryFinder.java:712)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getImplementationInstance(FactoryFinder.java:574)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.access$500(FactoryFinder.java:140)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:1122)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:381)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.verifyFactoriesExist(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:327)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getImplGivenPreviousImpl(FactoryFinder.java:692)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/enterprise/context/spi/Contextual
    at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.impl.util.ClassDeactivation.getClassDeactivator(ClassDeactivation.java:69)
    at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.impl.util.ClassDeactivation.isClassActivated(ClassDeactivation.java:50)
    at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.jsf2.impl.listener.request.CodiFacesContextFactory.isActivated(CodiFacesContextFactory.java:138)
    at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.jsf2.impl.listener.request.CodiFacesContextFactory.<init>(CodiFacesContextFactory.java:46)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.enterprise.context.spi.Contextual
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1711)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1556)
    ... 60 more
```

Comment: CODI is a CDI extension, so it requires CDI in first place. The exception is also telling exactly that. A class of CDI is missing in the classpath. CDI is usually already provided in Java EE application servers. However, your stacktrace hints that you're using Tomcat, which is a barebones JSP/Servlet container which doesn't ship with CDI (let alone JSF itself). You need to add CDI to Tomcat as well in order to fix this problem (as I'm no Maven guy, I can't tell how to do that, hence no answer from me here). An alternative is to upgrade to a real Java EE appserver like TomEE or Glassfish.

Comment: You can use the archetype to see what you need for configuring a CDI implementation. See http://myfaces.apache.org/ and search for 'archetype' on the page or look at one of the small examples shipped with CODI or one listed at https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/EXTCDI/External.

Comment: Thank you for your respond, however I was not able to solve the problem, I still got errors, nevermind :-(

Answer (score 0):

As I am Using Spring with JSF, I´m using a brazillian framework that uses myfaces orchestra scope as a background for the new scopes for Spring:

- "SameViewed" -> Just like @ViewScope (JSF)
- "AccessScoped" -> Just as ViewAccessScoped

It is a very good library, and I am having no more problems
with scopes on my project.

Sorry, for this is in portuguese, but I can translate or help you get started if there is an intrust shown...
The link to the portuguese tutorial:

http://lindbergframework.blogspot.com/2012/02/como-manter-o-estado-de-um-managedbean.html

Hope this helps!! :)

Comment: MyFaces Orchestra is an Add-on for Spring like CODI is for CDI. If you have an issue with your Spring config Orchestra wouldn't work as well. If you don't add CDI to your application, CODI can't work correctly. That shouldn't be a big surprise... And searching where javax.enterprise.context.spi.Contextual comes from shouldn't be that difficult ;) We are using CODI since 2 years in many big projects without any issue.